How can I manage the overflow/underflow of a variable containing the position of an axis?
In managing the position of an axis, the position value is contained in an 8-bit variable. It follows that the value of that variable will be 0->127..-128,-127..-1,0,1,2 for each revolution. However, it is necessary to take care of the lap number in order to have position control that is not limited to the single lap. What is the best system to handle this. In this system there are no traps for the change of revolution but only the value of the counting variable
I thought I would manage everything by making comparisons between the previous value and the current one and managing all the sign reversal conditions but I don't know if this is the correct system
